# PyQt5 Create QtWidgets.QCheckBox'es on Click Event in runtime

Tags: python, events, dynamic, pyqt5, qtwidgets

I've got a problem, that i have stumbled across several times.
I want to create an arbitrary number of `QCheckBoxes` on a `QPushButton` event.

I defined a function wich will be executed by clicking the `PushButton`. It should make some `CheckBoxes`, but nothing is shown an the `MainWindow`. However if I execute the function while creating the `MainWindow` it works perfectly fine.

I've tried to call the `.update()`, `.repaint()` functions in the called function, but nothing happened. I've also tried the janky `.hide()` `.show()` fix, but nothing here too.
I think I'm missing out on something big.

I include a Minimal example. For keeping things simple I always add two checkboxes, in my project it would depend on the amount of textfiles in a directory. I commented the function call at creating the `MainWindow` wich would work fine.

> minimal Code Example

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self.c_boxes = []
        
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton( 'HI',self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.action)
        #self.action()
        
    def action(self):
        for i in range(2):
            c_box=QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)
            c_box.move(10,25+ 25*i)
            self.c_boxes.append(c_box)

            
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Add `c_box.show()` after `c_box.move(10,25+ 25*i)`. You may want to use QT layouts manage widgets though.

Comment: Okay thank you, this fixed it for me :)